# FROM_UNIXTIME does not match DATE_ADD with seconds

Tags: mysql, date

Could somebody please explain why this differs?

```
SELECT 
  FROM_UNIXTIME(547164000),
  DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(0), INTERVAL 547164000 SECOND),
  @@session.time_zone
```

returns

```
1987-05-05 00:00:00
1987-05-04 23:00:00
SYSTEM
```

system's timezone is CEST, +0200 (obtained by command `date +%z`).

I am using this DATE_ADD method to handle negative timestamp as FROM_UNIXTIME does not support negative values.

Comment: I can't explain it, but running SET time_zone='+02:00'; seems to return the expected results

Comment: Yes, it solved it, thanks. SET time_zone='SYSTEM'; seems to be the problem. It looks like FROM_UNIXTIME and DATE_ADD use different SYSTEM value? ;)

Answer (score 0):

A MySQL server can be set up with its own time_zone, such that it doesn't behave like PHP's time(). That is, storing a time() value into a TIMESTAMP field and then displaying the resulting formatted date and time may not give the expected results. You have to be careful not to mix SQL and non-SQL timestamp usage, but stick to one or the other. Why exactly it gives different results for the two expressions is not clear to me, but could point up a bug in MySQL. You would *think* that adding N seconds to 0 time would give the same results as a plain N time... are you sure that they are formatting under exactly the same time_zone and DST/Summer Time rules?

Comment: Thanks for the answer and tips. But note this command is executed directly on MySql server and the timestamp is hardcoded on purpose.